# How to mark which class to cast to in c++?

Tags: c++, types, casting, template-meta-programming

I am looking for some way to mark the class I want to cast to. I am quite new here on the site so please feel free to improve tags or other things.

For example, if I have:

```
template<class C>
class Rotateable
{
    virtual void C Rotate() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Rotateable<Circle>
{
    Circle Rotate() { /*impl here*/ }
};

class Square : public Rotateable<Square>
{
    Square Rotate() { /*impl here*/ }
};
```

If I have a list or array of `Rotateable`s, how can I store somewhere (in `Rotateable`?) the information of what class to try and cast to, in a way that I can access at runtime?

Comment: You can't really have a list or array of `Rotatable` instances, since it's a template You can have a collection of `Rotabable<Circle>` and another collection of `Rotatable<Square>`, but you can't have both in a single collection unless you use e.g. `std::any`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I will see if I can alter it to work the way I mean.

Comment: Yes you are right it does not allow templates in lists. It really seems not possible to do. I will do better to inherit some enum marker instead or other ugly thing. Or wait in which version of c++ do we get std::any?

Comment: This just seems the perfect place for good old polymorphism, not templates.

Comment: @DeiDei : Yep I think you are right. I will need operators which work cross-class also.

Comment: You are looking for the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: @Steve No, sorry. It is too late for that. I solved it on my own, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I can help the guitarist's nephew over here instead. That will have to do.

Comment: Actually the visitor pattern is too much. Part of that is something called [Double Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) that is just for this type of problem and is a pattern in itself. Worth knowing even if you've already found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a virtual whose return type changes. But you can have type identifiers on polymorphic classes that tell you which class to cast to before calling the function. Take a look at something like this as the basic idea. (This is c++14 code. Feel free to strip out any parts that don't work for you if you aren't using c++14 features.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

size_t generate_id()
{
    static size_t id = 0;
    return id++;
}

template <typename T>
size_t type_id()
{
    static size_t id = generate_id();
    return id;
}

class BaseRotatable
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool is()
    {
        return type_id<T>() == type();
    }

    virtual size_t type() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Rotatable : public BaseRotatable
{
public:
    size_t type() override
    {
        return type_id<T>();
    }
};

class Circle : public Rotatable<Circle>
{
public:
    Circle Rotate()
    {
        return *this; // Make this do something fancier.
    }
};

class Square : public Rotatable<Square>
{
public:
    Square Rotate()
    {
        return *this; // Make this do something fancier.
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<BaseRotatable> factory(Args... args)
{
    T* ptr = new T(args...);
    return std::unique_ptr<BaseRotatable>{dynamic_cast<BaseRotatable*>(ptr)};
}

int main() {
    // Build a vector of rotatables.
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseRotatable>> rotatables;
    rotatables.emplace_back(factory<Circle>());
    rotatables.emplace_back(factory<Square>());

    for (auto& rotatable : rotatables)
    {
        // You can also use a switch here.
        if (rotatable->is<Circle>())
        {
            Circle& circle = *dynamic_cast<Circle*>(rotatable.get());
            auto new_circle = circle.Rotate();
            std::cout << "Type id: " << new_circle.type() << std::endl;
        }
        else if (rotatable->is<Square>())
        {
            Square& square = *dynamic_cast<Square*>(rotatable.get());
            auto new_square = square.Rotate();
            std::cout << "Type id: " << new_square.type() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the virtual to change return type, I want to enforce the inherited to implement certain functions returning objects of their own class.

Comment: You can't. The only way to enforce implementation is to have a virtual in the base class. And if base class has a virtual, it has a specific return type. It can't return something different in different derived classes. For each derived class to have a Rotate() function that returns its own type of object, each of these have to be distinct functions. And that means, they are completely independent of base class.

Comment: that is easy to do with curiously recurring template pattern. My struggle starts when I want to stuff objects deriving from those into a common list.

Comment: To put objects into common list, they should have a common base class, or be raw pointers. Either way, you'll need to identify which object is which as you take them off the list. Which is precisely what I do with type ids in the example. There are other ways to do that, of course. But you can't have a container of mixed types without doing some run-time work yourself. C++ does not maintain type information at run-time.

Comment: Yes type Ids are probably one way I could do it. Thank you.